# Axis web service consumer and Mule 3.6

Tags: web-services, soap, mule, axis, rpc

I'm going to try latest mule runtime to consume an old Axis web service.
Just trying to use "Web service consumer" component without success.
My first try on a method without parameters result in

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Failed to load transport: org/mule/transport axis (org.mule.api.registry.ServiceException). Message payload is of type: MuleUniversalConduit$1
at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:194) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1] 
...
```

this is my actual config

```
mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:tls="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls"
xmlns:ws="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.6.1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls/current/mule-tls.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd">
    <tls:context name="MyWSTLS_Context" doc:name="TLS Context">
        <tls:trust-store path="trustStore/truststore.ts" password="secret"/>
        <tls:key-store path="trustStore/keystore.jks" password="secret" keyPassword="toosecret"/>
    </tls:context>
    <ws:consumer-config name="MyWS_WS_getVersion_Consumer" wsdlLocation="Version.wsdl" service="VersionService" port="Version" serviceAddress="axis:http://staging.myws.com/myws/services/Version" doc:name="Web Service Consumer" connectorConfig="HTTPS_MyWSRequest_Configuration"/>
    <http:request-config name="HTTPS_MyWSRequest_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="staging.myws.com" port="443" basePath="/MyWS/services" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" tlsContext-ref="MyWSTLS_Context"/>
    <http:listener-config name="MyWS_Listener_Configuration"  host="0.0.0.0" port="8081"   doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="wsconsumerFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="MyWS_Listener_Configuration" path="/consumer" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="MyWS_WS_getVersion_Consumer" operation="getVersion" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

The service is an rpc style an requires array of strings as parameters.
Any hint appreciated.

Comment: The axis transport is still part of Mule 3.6 ( https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/tree/mule-3.6.1/transports/axis ): did you try to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deprecated but still shipped for backwards compatibility transport for axis is getting into your way.

Just change the `axis:` from the service address, hopefully it should work if there are no other problems.

Comment: it starts working but something is still to fix because when run the simplest call that has no parameters to supply, I get the following error:
'apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Cannot invoke WS call without an Operation. Set the method param on your endpointUri or on the endpoint itself. Failed to route event via endpoint: AxisMessageDispatcher{this=798b9306, endpoint=axis://staging.myws.com/myws/services/Version, disposed=false}. Message payload is of type: MuleUniversalConduit$1'
Something related to encoded messages?